# 'Zero'Object has no attribute 'sin'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

I am trying to compose a matrix with a function and pass through different values of n, r to create different columns and rows. I have it working when I don't define the functions but once they are defined I can not pass the values through without getting the error 'zero' object has no attribute 'sin'

I've already tried float, and converting to numpy

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, pi, sqrt, cos
from sympy import sqrt, sin, cos, pi, Matrix
#from sympy.abc import n, r, x, L
A=w**2/2 
Phi_n= sqrt(2/L)*sym.sin(n*sym.pi*x/L + n*sym.pi/2) #When n*np.pi*x     
Phi_r= sqrt(2/L)*sym.sin(r*sym.pi*x/L + r*sym.pi/2)

V_Func=A*integrate(Phi_r*x**2*Phi_n, (x, -L/2, L/2))

from sympy.utilities.lambdify import  lambdify, implemented_function
from sympy import Function

V_F = lambdify((n, r), V_Func)
V_F(0,0)
```

Returns 0

```
from sympy import Matrix
N = 5

sym.Matrix(N, N, lambda n,r:V_F(n,r))
```

This returns the error, zero object has no attribute sin

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call   last)
<ipython-input-222-c996f5317753> in <module>
      1 from sympy import Matrix
      2 N = 5
----> 3 sym.Matrix(N, N, lambda n,r:V_F(n,r))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.py in    __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    431 class MutableDenseMatrix(DenseMatrix, MatrixBase):
    432     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
--> 433         return cls._new(*args, **kwargs)
434 
    435     @classmethod

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.py in  _new(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    443             rows, cols, flat_list = args
    444         else:
--> 445             rows, cols, flat_list =     cls._handle_creation_inputs(*args, **kwargs)
    446             flat_list = list(flat_list) # create a shallow     copy
    447         self = object.__new__(cls)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py in _handle_creation_inputs(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   2337                     flat_list.extend(
   2338                         [cls._sympify(op(cls._sympify(i), cls._sympify(j)))
-> 2339                          for j in range(cols)])
   2340 
   2341             # Matrix(2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py in    <listcomp>(.0)
   2337                     flat_list.extend(
   2338                         [cls._sympify(op(cls._sympify(i),  cls._sympify(j)))
  -> 2339                          for j in range(cols)])
   2340 
   2341             # Matrix(2, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4])

<ipython-input-222-c996f5317753> in <lambda>(n, r)
      1 from sympy import Matrix
      2 N = 5
----> 3 sym.Matrix(N, N, lambda n,r:V_F(n,r))

<lambdifygenerated-51> in _lambdifygenerated(n, r)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(n, r):
----> 2     return     ((1/2)*w**2*select([logical_or.reduce((logical_and.reduce((equal(n, 0),equal(r, 0))),logical_and.reduce((equal(n, 0),equal(n, r),equal(r, 0))),logical_and.reduce((equal(n, 0),equal(r, 0),equal(n, -r))),logical_and.reduce((equal(n, 0),equal(n, r),equal(r, 0),equal(n, -r))))),logical_or.reduce((equal(n, -r),logical_and.reduce((equal(n, 0),equal(n, -r))),logical_and.reduce((equal(n, r),equal(n, -r))),logical_and.reduce((equal(r, 0),equal(n, -r))),logical_and.reduce((equal(n, 0),equal(n, r),equal(n, -r))),logical_and.reduce((equal(n, r),equal(r, 0),equal(n, -r))))),logical_or.reduce((equal(n, r),logical_and.reduce((equal(n, 0),equal(n, r))),logical_and.reduce((equal(n, r),equal(r, 0))))),True], [0,-2*((1/48)*L**3 - 1/8*L**3/(pi**2*r**2))/L + 2*(-1/48*L**3*sin(pi*r)**2 - 1/48*L**3*cos(pi*r)**2 + (1/8)*L**3*sin(pi*r)*cos(pi*r)/(pi*r) - 1/8*L**3*sin(pi*r)**2/(pi**2*r**2) + (1/8)*L**3*cos(pi*r)**2/(pi**2*r**2) - 1/4*L**3*sin(pi*r)*cos(pi*r)/(pi**3*r**3))/L,-2*(-1/48*L**3 + (1/8)*L**3/(pi**2*r**2))/L + 2*((1/48)*L**3*sin(pi*r)**2 + (1/48)*L**3*cos(pi*r)**2 - 1/8*L**3*sin(pi*r)*cos(pi*r)/(pi*r) + (1/8)*L**3*sin(pi*r)**2/(pi**2*r**2) - 1/8*L**3*cos(pi*r)**2/(pi**2*r**2) + (1/4)*L**3*sin(pi*r)*cos(pi*r)/(pi**3*r**3))/L,-2*(2*pi*L**3*n**3*r/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) - 2*pi*L**3*n*r**3/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6))/L + 2*((1/4)*pi**2*L**3*n**5*sin(pi*r)*cos(pi*n)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) - 1/4*pi**2*L**3*n**4*r*sin(pi*n)*cos(pi*r)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) - pi*L**3*n**4*sin(pi*n)*sin(pi*r)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) - 1/2*pi**2*L**3*n**3*r**2*sin(pi*r)*cos(pi*n)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) - 2*pi*L**3*n**3*r*cos(pi*n)*cos(pi*r)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) - 2*L**3*n**3*sin(pi*r)*cos(pi*n)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) + (1/2)*pi**2*L**3*n**2*r**3*sin(pi*n)*cos(pi*r)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) + 6*L**3*n**2*r*sin(pi*n)*cos(pi*r)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) + (1/4)*pi**2*L**3*n*r**4*sin(pi*r)*cos(pi*n)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) + 2*pi*L**3*n*r**3*cos(pi*n)*cos(pi*r)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) - 6*L**3*n*r**2*sin(pi*r)*cos(pi*n)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) - 1/4*pi**2*L**3*r**5*sin(pi*n)*cos(pi*r)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) + pi*L**3*r**4*sin(pi*n)*sin(pi*r)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6) + 2*L**3*r**3*sin(pi*n)*cos(pi*r)/(-pi**3*n**6 + 3*pi**3*n**4*r**2 - 3*pi**3*n**2*r**4 + pi**3*r**6))/L], default=numpy.nan))

AttributeError: 'Zero' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are mixing `numpy` and `sympy`.  `np.sin` expects an numpy array as input.  Or it makes an array from the input.  If the result is an object dtype array, then it tries to do `elmt.sin()` for each element of the array.  Hence the attempt to get a `sin` method for your `sympy` object.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem I changed one line of code to sym.Matrix(N, N, lambda n,r:V_F(n,r), 'mpmath') and that worked. Thank you everyone for the help!!